# How to mock correctly some methods class for Jest?

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

Let 's say I have a class like:

at ./src/myClass.ts

```
class myClass{

    methodA(){
    ...
    }

    methodB(){
    ...
    }
}
```

and I neeed to mock method A, so what I did is to create the file

.src/**mocks**/myClass.ts

```
class myClass{

    methodA(){
    ...
    }
}
```

then at ./**tests**/myClass.test.ts

```
'use strict';
import { myClass } from "../src/myClass";
jest.mock('../src/myClass');

describe('myClass', () => {
    it('returns methodB',  () => {
        const c = new myClass();
        //this one mocked correctly
        c.methodA();
        // how can I instruct jest to use the original method?
        const data= c.methodB();

        expect(data)
          .toMatchObject({})
    }, 
    3000)
});
```

as mentioned in the above comments I cant figure out how to use original methodB

I'm guessing that I'm mocking entire class. And I should go for mocking single class methods instead.
What is the jest practice to create a mock file to mock only certain class methods?

Comment: even if you achieve that, test will be really hard to maintain. Much easier to mock 3rd level dependency that causes unpredictability(`Math.random`, `new Date`, `fetch` etc)

Answer (score 0):

`__mocks__` directory and `jest.mock`, choose one. The following example using `jest.mock`:

`myClass.ts`:

```js
export class myClass {
  methodA() {
    return 'real a';
  }

  methodB() {
    return 'real b';
  }
}
```

`myClass.test.ts`:

```js
import { myClass } from './myClass';

jest.mock('./myClass', () => {
  const { myClass: originalMyClass } = require.requireActual('./myClass');
  const mMyClass = {
    methodA: jest.fn().mockReturnValueOnce('mock a'),
    methodB: originalMyClass.prototype.methodB,
  };
  return { myClass: jest.fn(() => mMyClass) };
});

describe('60633642', () => {
  it('should mock methodA', () => {
    const c = new myClass();
    const actual = c.methodA();
    expect(jest.isMockFunction(c.methodA)).toBeTruthy();
    expect(actual).toBe('mock a');
    expect(c.methodA).toBeCalledTimes(1);
  });

  it('should call original methodB', () => {
    const c = new myClass();
    const actual = c.methodB();
    expect(jest.isMockFunction(c.methodB)).toBeFalsy();
    expect(actual).toBe('real b');
  });
});
```

unit test results with coverage report:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/60633642/myClass.test.ts
  60633642
    ✓ should mock methodA (6ms)
    ✓ should call original methodB (2ms)

------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File        | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files   |   85.71 |      100 |   66.67 |   83.33 |                   
 myClass.ts |   85.71 |      100 |   66.67 |   83.33 | 3                 
------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        4.797s, estimated 9s
```

Comment: I wanted to use the __mocks__ way since it looks to me cleaner, less code in test file. If I remove line jest.mock('../src/myClass'); from test file it wont look for the class in __mocks__. It seems... isn't it?